# Embedded Xinu for RPi

Tags: kernel, cross-compilation

I have completed with setting up the cross compiler but stuck with the compiling part. I have build all the gnu binutils and the gcc successfully in the directory: **/home/admin/xinu/opt**. But while running the command `$ make -C compile PLATFORM=arm-rpi`, I get an error- **arm-none-eabi-gcc not found**. Also it asks to read the README.compiling file. 
I am doing this on ubuntu on my laptop.

Answer (score -1):

It means what is says it can't find the compiler executable for GCC which is the executable file arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe.

The make utility hasn't been given the path to the executable and so it can't run the compiler. Basically it can't run what it can't find .... so fix the path.